# React Axios to return data from MYSql

Tags: reactjs

I have this React.JS code to return a list of products. The console.log returns the right set of data. But when displaying the data, the display code returns the Error:

```
TypeError: products.map is not a function
```

The code:

```
import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CCol, CRow } from "@coreui/react";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../../../axrootpath';

function Products() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('api/products');
        setProducts(response.data);
**{/*The following line returns the correct data set */}**
        console.log(products);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.response) {
          // Not in the 200 response range 
          console.log(err.response.data);
          console.log(err.response.status);
          console.log(err.response.headers);
        } else {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    }

    fetchProducts();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="animated fadeIn">
      <CRow>
        <CCol xs={12}>
          <table
            id="productListTable"
            className="table table-striped table-bproductd"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Product Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Account Number</th>
                <th>Product Type</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Packing Type</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{products.map( (products) => {
          return (
            <tr key={products.prt_no}>
              <td>{products.DSCRPT}</td>
              <td>{products.ITEM_GROUP}</td>
              <td>{products.ACC_GROUP}</td>
              <td>{products.MATERIAL}</td>
              <td>{products.UI}</td>
              <td>{products.PU}</td>
            </tr>
          );
          })}</tbody>
          </table>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

The console.log(products) looks like that:
Object
products: Array(1318)
[0 … 99]
0: {PRT_NO: 'CU-STND1BLK', DSCRPT: 'Cu Stnd. PVC 1mm  -  Black', ITEM_GROUP: 'WIRES', ACC_GROUP: 'WIRES', MATERIAL: 'Y', …}
1: {PRT_NO: 'CU-STND1BLU', DSCRPT: 'Cu Stnd. PVC 1mm  -  Blue', ITEM_GROUP: 'WIRES', ACC_GROUP: 'WIRES', MATERIAL: 'Y', …}
2: {PRT_NO: 'CU-STND1RED', DSCRPT: 'Cu Stnd. PVC 1mm  -  Red', ITEM_GROUP: 'WIRES', ACC_GROUP: 'WIRES', MATERIAL: 'Y', …}
3: {PRT_NO: 'CU-STND1YLW', DSCRPT: 'Cu Stnd. PVC 1mm  -  Ylw.', ITEM_GROUP: 'WIRES', ACC_GROUP: 'WIRES', MATERIAL: 'Y', …}

Comment: Can you please provide what the ```console.log(products)``` return ?

Comment: The returned response from the server is not an array that why map is not function there.